# visual studio 2019 not show add new item Report rdlc

Tags: wpf, reporting-services, visual-studio-2019, rdlc, .net-core-3.1

I installed Microsoft Reporting Services Projects VS2019 extention and ssdt based on this link on vs 2019 : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15

I have wpf core project in vs 2019 , but when I right click and select add new item , there is not Report item to select. How can we add .rdlc file to wpf core project?

Answer (score 8):

I found it , we have to install **Microsoft RDLC Report Designer** extention on VS 2019. Now I have **Report** and **Report Wizard** items in add new item.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001

Comment: Even after insalling this, still cannot view the add an rdlc item option

Comment: @Bellash the reason for this is that even though Microsoft is offering the ability to view and edit RDLC files in .NET 5+, the ability to actually add them will no longer be possible going forward. For now my solution is to add an existing RDLC file and edit from there.

Answer (score 3):

You have to install this component separately after installing 2019.

Once VS2019 is installed.. go to Tools -> Get tools and Features. Search for Reporting Services and install it.

Then you can create new SSRS projects

Comment: I don't want to create ssrs project. I only want to add a rdlc file to my wpf core project and print it.

Comment: maybe if you install the above add on, then it might be available when you add a new item? If not, I'll just delete my answer

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exact problem. Here is a workaround: Create an xml file containing the following minimal content. Then change the extension of the file from `MyReport.xml` to `MyReport.rdlc` in order to have rdlc extension.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" 
xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">

<Width>6.5in</Width>
<Body>
 <Height>2in</Height>
</Body>
<rd:ReportTemplate>true</rd:ReportTemplate>
<Page>
</Page>
</Report>
```

I came to this solution, after installing all suggested tools/templates, still could not view the option/button to add a rdlc tool.

Using this technique you can now open/edit the file in the reportViewer Designer inside Visual Studio 2019

PS: This solution applies to .net 5 projects, and .net core 3.1 projects also, has chance to work on .net core 2.x project (didn't test this last).

Answer (score 2):

From Visual Studio
Extensions Menu => Manage Extensions => Search for RDLC =>Install => close and open your visual studio

Answer (score 0):

Well.. after searching a lot, i installed Visual Studio 2015. create a winform project and added it to my Project in Visual Studio 2019

I can create datasets, rdlc report, just in this winform project, and then i add it to my wwwroot folder

[My project, and the winform project at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bBBY.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).